# JWT TOKEN issue

Tags: node.js, authentication, security, jwt, backend

Hi guys i am developing a authentication backend and confused a bit like if i am generating the jwt do i need to store it in database.

Like i want to the user to get signed in than a token will generate and than stores in cookies and than whenever the user visits a secret page (need authentication to open) he send a request from that page and jwt will verify the token but does it work after expiration or not? and do i need to store the jwt in database?

I want to know about the best practices for jwt

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to store jwt token into database. It is not a good practice.

```
const express = require("express")

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const app = express()

const jwt_secret = 'some_secret_text'

app.post('/generate-token', (req, res) => {

// user id will be the _id of that user in database

  const token = jwt.sign({ userID: "userID" }, jwt_secret,{expiresIn : '12h'})
  
 res.writeHead(200, {
   "Set-Cookie": `token=${token}`,
   "Content-Type": `application/json`,
 })
  
  res.json({message : "message"})

})

// cookie parser

function parseCookies (request) {

const list = {};

const cookieHeader = request.headers?.cookie;
if (!cookieHeader) return list;

cookieHeader.split(`;`).forEach(function(cookie) {
    let [ name, ...rest] = cookie.split(`=`);
    name = name?.trim();
    if (!name) return;
    const value = rest.join(`=`).trim();
    if (!value) return;
    list[name] = decodeURIComponent(value);
});

return list;
}

// validate token

app.post('/validate-token', (req, res) => {
  ...

  const cookie = parseCookie(req);

  const verified = jwt.verify(cookie.token, jwtSecretKey,{expiresIn : '12h'});

// It returns false if it is expired or not valid

// It returns the object containing userid if it is valid. You can perform some operations with that userid in database.
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reponse.
i want to know one  more thing 
if i save the jwt in database and expire the token in 12h and than user logged in and logged out in just 10 min means the jwt token is not expired than ? 
whatsa the solution to expire the jwt after log out

Comment: U don't need to make the token expire when the user logged out. Instead just remove cookie

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to store JWT token in database, if you are developing backend only. u just need to generate the JWT token. front-end developer handle the JWT token from them side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).